# Dynamically brute-force all numerical combinations

Tags: python, combinatorics

As the title says I'm trying to get all possible numerical combinations for an unknown number of parameters. I don't mind if you use pandas or numpy. See the code section to understand my problem easily. Any help would be appreciated.

```
# n can be any integer. 4 is just an example.
n = 4 
possibleValues = range(1, n+1)
# [1, 2, 3, 4]

# The number of elements in this list is unknown. It's only 2 elements just for example
parameters = ["foo", "boo"]

Expected results:
{'foo': 1, 'boo': 1},
{'foo': 1, 'boo': 2},
{'foo': 1, 'boo': 3},
{'foo': 1, 'boo': 4},

{'foo': 2, 'boo': 1},
{'foo': 2, 'boo': 2},
{'foo': 2, 'boo': 3},
{'foo': 2, 'boo': 4}

...

{'foo': 4, 'boo': 1},
{'foo': 4, 'boo': 2},
{'foo': 4, 'boo': 3},
{'foo': 4, 'boo': 4}
```

Comment: By "help" do you mean someone else doing it for you? What have you tried that didn't work? In what way did your attempt not work? Check out the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on asking good questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[itertools.product()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) will do this for you. You need to tell it how many to repeat, which in this case is the length of the dict keys. Then just zip them up and pass to `dict()`:

```
from itertools import product

n = 4 
possibleValues = range(1, n+1)
parameters = ["foo", "boo"]

[dict(zip(parameters, pair)) for pair in product(possibleValues, repeat=len(parameters))]
```

Which gives you:

```
[{'foo': 1, 'boo': 1},
 {'foo': 1, 'boo': 2},
 {'foo': 1, 'boo': 3},
 {'foo': 1, 'boo': 4},
 {'foo': 2, 'boo': 1},
 {'foo': 2, 'boo': 2},
 {'foo': 2, 'boo': 3},
 {'foo': 2, 'boo': 4},
 {'foo': 3, 'boo': 1},
 {'foo': 3, 'boo': 2},
 {'foo': 3, 'boo': 3},
 {'foo': 3, 'boo': 4},
 {'foo': 4, 'boo': 1},
 {'foo': 4, 'boo': 2},
 {'foo': 4, 'boo': 3},
 {'foo': 4, 'boo': 4}]
```